# Geometric effect of a vector multiplied by the imaginary number

Tags: linear-algebra

If $v$ is a vector then $\alpha v$, where $\alpha$ is a scalar, is also a vector. If $\alpha$ is a non-zero real number, we know intuitively that $\alpha v$ is the vector $v$  "stretched" ($\alpha\geq1$) or "compressed" ($\alpha<1$). What is geometrical effect on $v$ when $\alpha$ is the imaginary number $i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for complex numbers

$$|z\cdot w|=|z|\cdot |w| \quad \arg(z\cdot w)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)$$

then for $\vec v\in \mathbb{C^n}$, by $z\cdot \vec v$ each complex component is streched by |z| and rotated by $\arg(z)$.